# Crashing When selecting video in android Q

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My Below code working fine rest of the android versions but crashing in android Q when I tried to select video

Added write and read permission 
My SDK Version is 28.0.2
Video recording is working fine for above code

Using this below code to start intent

```
    val videoIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK) 
    videoIntent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "video/*") 
    videoIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true) 
    videoIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true) 
    videoIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) startActivityForResult(videoIntent, 
    GALLERY_VIDEO)
```

In OnActivityResult

```
if (data?.data != null) {
                if (data.clipData != null) {
                    val mClipData = data.clipData
                    for (i in 0 until mClipData!!.itemCount) {
                        val item = mClipData.getItemAt(i)
                        val uri = item.uri
                        val videoPath = fileUtil.getVideoPath(this, uri)
                        if (videoPath != null) {
                            videoList.add(VideoType(videoPath, videoPath))
                        }
                        videoPath?.let { MediaType(it, videoPath, VIDEO) }?.let { mediaUrls.add(it) }
                        videoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                } else {
                    val contentURI = data.data
                    val videoPath = fileUtil.getVideoPath(this, contentURI)
                    val type = videoPath?.let { MediaType(it, contentURI.toString(), VIDEO) }
                    if (videoPath != null) {
                        videoList.add(VideoType(videoPath, videoPath))
                    }
                    videoPath?.let { MediaType(it, videoPath, VIDEO) }?.let { mediaUrls.add(it) }
                    videoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
```

getVideoPath method

```
fun getVideoPath(context: Context, uri: Uri?): String? {
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
    var contentUri = ""
    val cursor =
            context.contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection,
                    null, null, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        contentUri = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
        cursor.close()
    }
    return contentUri
}
```

Log message

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/26/ORIGINAL/NONE/529191973 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F26/ORIGINAL/NONE/529191973} }} to activity {com.rizek.android.users/com.rizek.android.users.ui.mediaupload.MediaUploadActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4845)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4886)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column latitude
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:944)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:880)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:836)
    at com.rizek.android.users.utils.file.FileUtil.getVideoPath(FileUtil.kt:41)
    at com.rizek.android.users.ui.mediaupload.MediaUploadActivity.onActivityResult(MediaUploadActivity.kt:244)
```

Comment: Your stack trace does not seem to match your code (error is for `latitude`, which you are not requesting). Regardless, `getVideoPath()` was never reliable and is pointless on Android 10 and higher (`DATA` is deprecated and you don't have filesystem access to that content), so please get rid of it and stop thinking in terms of files. Also note that your two extras are not documented to be supported by `ACTION_PICK`, so do not rely upon them.

Comment: DATA is deprecated in google documentation they suggested using the file descriptor but how can I get file URI from file descriptor object

Comment: "how can I get file URI from file descriptor object" -- that is not possible. Use the `Uri` directly, such as by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare "Your stack trace does not seem to match your code (error is for latitude, which you are not requesting)." - I have actually encountered this as well - I did not query the `latitude` column, but I get the same crash - I asked a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586124/illegalargumentexception-invalid-column-latitude

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, managed to get it to work by
Changing the Intent from ACTION_PICK, and adding extra flags, like:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "video/*");
        ((AppCompatActivity) context).startActivityForResult(i, Utils.VIDEO_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

then in onActivityResult() getting a persistable permission.

```
        if (requestCode == Utils.VIDEO_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(
                    videoUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            ((PhotosViewModel) mModel).videoChosen(videoUri);
        }
```

Finally, after these changes I managed to get the thumbnail with:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    try {
         Bitmap thumbnail =
                    getApplication().getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(
                                    uri, new Size(300, 300), null);

         } catch (IOException e) {}
```

AND I was able to access the video using

```
getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(videoURI))
```

as well as use the URI in a videoView to play the video. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: By the way, discovered afterwards that for android 9 and lower, I still had to use the old way of doing stuff  - else I couldnt get the thumb.